# Marking the bottom right-hand corner of a beamer slide to signal section change

Tags: beamer, positioning

The goal is to place a single character in the bottom right-hand corner of selected sides to indicate a new section begins on the next slide. This prompts the speaker to conclude remarks on the current section and transition to the next topic.

If the next slide begins a new subsection, use `\Rightarrow`. If the next slide is a new section, use `\Longrightarrow`.

There has been some success using this snippet,

```
\begin{textblock*}{1cm}(1.136\textwidth,8.9cm)
   {\Rightarrow}
\end{textblock*}
```

but sometimes it does not work or it conflicts with the package `tikz`.

Surely there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can conveniently position symbols in the bottom right corner with the `\logo{...}` macro
- to automatically add them on the pages before a new section starts, you can compare the current page number to `\insertsectionendpage`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\logo{
  \ifnum\thepage=\insertsectionendpage
    \Huge$\Rightarrow$
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
    
\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame}   
\end{document}
```